# How to connect to MySQL using Docksal?

Tags: 8

I'm using Docksal as a local environment. How do I connect to the MySQL database in the Docksal container? Can I just use my local instance of MySQL instead? Also if anyone knows how to import a database for use with the Docksal MySQL instance that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try connecting to it with HeidiSQL or SequelPro?

Comment: @Kevin Yes, I tried with MySQL workbench. There's a command that you can run that shows the IP of the DB, but does not work for mac...

Comment: Is it because you need to connect over ssh tunnel instead of standard connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connecting to a local MySQL DB did not work, however, this did:

`cd docroot`

`fin db import /path/to/.sql/file`

More can be found here https://docs.docksal.io/service/db/access/.